# Disabling rotation for current screen?

Tags: ios, interface-orientation

Is it possible to enable/disable rotation parameter for current screen or this property is for all application?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    //Choose your available orientation, you can also support more tipe using the symbol |
    //e.g. return (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight)
    return (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait);
}
```

Comment: Note that this will only work in case the `ViewController` isn't embedded into a `NavigationController`, It has to be called modally, since the `NavigationController` is responsible for the autorotation and you can't change it for just one `ViewController`

Comment: @B: I use this method in my viewController that isn't in a UINavigationController.

@FreeNickname: This methods need to be inserted in the his rootViewController.

Comment: @MatteoGobbi, yes, sorry. I removed my comment to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: If I want to enable rotation to this screen I need to return all InterfaceOrientations in supportedInterfaceOrientations?

Comment: Yes, or just the interface you want make available.

Comment: If I have ViewController embedded into a NavigationController how can I use it?

Comment: you can use it in the navigationController with an IF statement where you check what type of viewController is actually presented and returning the supported orientation for it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple ViewControllers within a NavigationController, and you wish to disable rotation in **one** of them only, you need to set and control rotation within ApplicationDelegate. Here is how to do it in Swift...

In AppDelegate.swift:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {


var blockRotation: Bool = false

func application(application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow window: UIWindow?) -> Int {

    if (self.blockRotation) {
        println("supportedInterfaceOrientations - PORTRAIT")
        return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait.rawValue)
    } else {
        println("supportedInterfaceOrientations - ALL")
        return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.All.rawValue)
    }
}
```

In the ViewController that you want to block rotation, add **UIApplicationDelegate** to your class...

```
class LoginViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UIApplicationDelegate {
```

and then create a reference to the AppDelegate...

```
var appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
```

In viewDidLoad, set appDelegate.blockRotation = true:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    appDelegate.blockRotation = true

}
```

In viewWillAppear, set the orientation to force the device to the chosen orientation (Portrait in this example):

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

    let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait.rawValue
    UIDevice.currentDevice().setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")

}
```

Then in viewWillDisappear, or in prepareForSegue, set appDelegate.blockRotation = false:

```
override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    appDelegate.blockRotation = false
}
```

This will block rotation in the one view controller within a Navigation Controller that contains multiple ViewControllers. Hope this helps.