# Rotate just one view to Landscape

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, landscape, uiinterfaceorientation

I am working on a iPAD application with MasterDetailView. From my tableView I am pushing another ViewController on detailViewController. I want this another ViewController to be displayed in landscape mode.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [_detailViewController.navigationController pushViewController:[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ABCViewController"]  animated:YES];
}
```

I want this ABCViewController to be displayed in Landscape only view. All my other view supports both the orientation. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Insert in this new viewController:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    //Choose your available orientation, you can also support more tipe using the symbol |
    //e.g. return (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight)
    return (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight);
}
```

as i already written here:

[Disabling rotation for current screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23468758/disabling-rotation-for-current-screen/23468833?noredirect=1#comment36002264_23468833)