# lock one UIview in Landspace in ios 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, orientation

I am trying to lock one of the views in my app to LandscapeRight. The code I used is shown below.

```
// To landscape

- (NSUInteger) supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return NO;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation) preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
}
```

However, it still rotates.

Do I miss something?

Comment: Is your view the view of a viewController which is displayed into another container viewController , such as a UInavigationController ?

Comment: Yes, I used segue to display from tableViewController to viewController. @BarbaraRodeker

Answer (score 1):

I reply to this question here:

[Disabling rotation for current screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23468758/disabling-rotation-for-current-screen/23468833#23468833)

you should use:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    //Choose your available orientation, you can also support more tipe using the symbol |
    //e.g. return (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight)
    return (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight);
}
```

If you **return NO**, your `viewController` doesn't enter in the method `supportedInterfaceOrientations`.

Comment: I used segue to display from tableViewController to viewController. Do you have any other method?

Comment: What mean that you use Storyboard? this doesn't change my answer. You need to implement this code in your viewController. What is the problem..?