# Return to portrait after landscape view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I have an application that need to be on portrait orientation for all view, and one view (`UIWebview`) that need to support portrait and lansdscape orietation.

To set the default portrait orientation , I put this in my app delegate:

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window{
//NSLog(@"PlayWithWSWithLibAppDelegate -- supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow");
if(flagOrientationAll == YES){
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
} else {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}}
```

And I have manage to arrange my webview to portrait/landscape regarding the user orientation using this method (got this from stackoverflow also)

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
delegate.flagOrientationAll = YES;
}

-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
//NSLog(@"viewWillDisappear -- Start");
AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
delegate.flagOrientationAll = NO;
}
```

And to present portrait and landscape i using two UIView:

```
-(void)viewWillLayoutSubviews {
    BOOL layoutIsPortrait = UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(self.interfaceOrientation);
    if (layoutIsPortrait) {
        self.view = self.pView;
    [self.pView addSubview:pwebView];
}else{
    self.view = self.lView;
    [self.lView addSubview:lwebView];
}}
```

Then to dismiss the webview i using this code:

```
- (IBAction)doneButtonTapped:(id)sender
{
   [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

However when it dismiss in landscape state, the previous screen (the screen that call the webview) present in landscape instead of the default(portrait).
How i can make after the webview dismiss it will still present in portrait?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should implement the **supported orientation** for each `viewController`:

Like i wrote [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23468758/disabling-rotation-for-current-screen/23468833#23468833):

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    //Choose your available orientation, you can also support more tipe using the symbol |
    //e.g. return (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight)
    return (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3.0:**

(Added to the ViewController that calls the landscape-able view)

```
override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
    return true
}

override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return .portrait
}
```